# Exclude entities for Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Data Rest in one of my projects, and Spring Data Rest will create an HTTP endpoint for each of my entities. There's a few entities which I'd like to exclude form this scanning however. Is there an option to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Spring data rest uses Spring HATEOAS. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-customize-http-endpoints .

You can exclude entities from scanning by adding `@RestResource(exported = false)` annotation:

```
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public class User {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data Rest will provide endpoints for your *Repositories*, not Entities

Ideally, you should only create repositories for your [Aggregate Roots](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html), not for each Entity

If you have other repositories though, you can annotate them with `@RepositoryRestResource(exported=false)`, and SDR won't expose them

Answer (score 0):

To disable the endpoint for entity `Order`, add `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)` to its repository interface.

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> { }
```

See more configuration in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.setting-repository-detection-strategy

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a repository, I only have an entity.